# Check for existing childnodes of treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

I know to this question is a lot of content in the internet and also on sof. But even by trying I cant find a working way to solve my problem.

I have a TreeView that gets filled in runtime...

```
foreach( dynamic obj in data )
{
    if (!rdpTreeView.Nodes.ContainsKey(obj.customername))
    {
        TreeNode customer = new TreeNode(obj.customername);
        customer.Name = obj.customername;
        rdpTreeView.Nodes.Add(customer);
    }
    //[some code]
}
```

In `[some code]` I also want to fill some childnodes as well...

```
TreeNode server = rdpTreeView.Nodes[obj.customername] ;
if (!server.Nodes.ContainsKey(obj.servername))
{
    TreeNode myTn = new TreeNode(obj.servername);
    rdpTreeView.Nodes[obj.customername].Nodes.Add(myTn);
}
```

But how ever I try, my `If`-clause won`t match in any way...

My Treeview looks like

```
John
    Doe
Max
    Molly
    Molly  //<=== I want to deny this node
Jack
    Jill
```

Since my data comes from a database, there could be a lot of same entry that i want to deny. Calling data distinct would filter to much results...

So my question is:

**How can I check for existing childnodes ?**

Other sample use functions that dont even exists. At least my VS doesnt knows them.

Comment: Use the TreeView Find function.

Comment: In your "[some code]" surely if you created said node and called it server - rather than refinding it, you could just do server.Nodes.Add(myTn) ?

Comment: @BugFinder but i dont want to add it when it allready exists :D and TreeNode has no `ContainsKey`

Comment: But Nodes does..

Comment: Yes nodes does. But not treeview.nodes['john']